# How to change the default application for a certain file extention on Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm working on a remote RHEL 7.9 Server and i don't have Admin privileges. When i try to open a file with a certain extention in the GUI: Right click -> "open with other application" -> "View all applications", i don't find the programm i need, since it was custom made for us and it's stored in "/usr/local/bin". The application has no "*.desktop" file. I don't have mimeopen installed and i can't install it.

Do you know some way to set a default application from the terminal without Admin privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The application has no "*.desktop" file

Then create one. You can put custom .desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications/` and they will show up in the same list together with system-wide files.

A very basic .desktop file for launching an app might look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Notepad
Icon=notepad
Exec=/usr/local/bin/notepad %f
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/html;
```

The file manager's "Open with" settings are kept in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` (for older graphical environments this might be located in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`). You should use the `xdg-mime default` tool to make changes, but the overall format is like this:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=mousepad.desktop
```

(As you can see, it's the actual config system that needs a .desktop file – it's not just the file manager's app list that wants one.)